# Notation confusion about sum of $\Lambda (n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

This is hopefully a small point of notation I am missing. I am used to the first two equalities below.

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \Lambda(n) n^{-s} =
\sum_{p \mbox{ prime}} \sum_{m \geq 1} \Lambda(p^m) (p^m)^{-s} = 
\sum_{p \mbox{ prime}} \sum_{m \geq 1} (\log p) p^{-ms}$$  $$=
\sum_{p \mbox{ prime}}(\log p) \sum_{m \geq 1} p^{-ms}.
$$

What in the notation of the second sum just above allows us to ascribe values to $p?$ To me it looks like the product:

$$(\log 2+\log3+\log 5+...)(p^{-s}+p^{-2s}+p^{-3s}+...) $$

Apparently we should we read it as (?)

$$\sum_p  \left(\log p\sum_{m\geq1}p^{-ms} \right)$$

$$ = (\log 2)(2^{-s}+2^{-2s}+2^{-3s}+...)+(\log 3)(3^{-s}+3^{-2s}+3^{-3s}+...)$$

If so does this second line offer some advantage over the last (double sum) in the first line?

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear $\;\displaystyle \sum_{p \mbox{ prime}}(\log p) \sum_{m \geq 1} p^{-ms}\;$ usually means $\;\displaystyle \sum_p  \left(\log p\sum_{m\geq1}p^{-ms} \right)$. Concerning your product (at the middle) is doesn't make much sense since you would have a (divergent) sum over $p$ at the left and $p$ as a parameter that we should rather write as $\;\displaystyle \left(\sum_{p'}(\log p')\right) \sum_{m \geq 1} p^{-ms}\;$ (in number theory $p$ and variants are usually considered prime).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thanks much, it should have been obvious but I hadn't seen it in this form before.

Comment: Glad it clarified things @daniel. More common ambiguities appear with sums for example $\sum_n f(n) - C$. In this case you'll have to decide from context (or evaluation) that the intention is to subtract $C$ once or to every term. In any case parenthesis or reordering (writing $-C$ at the left) should resolve the ambiguity,